# Remove Radio checked when user click input in the field? FYI:jquery ui for "datepicker". (Jfiddle)

Tags: java, jquery, input, datepicker, radio-group

http://jsfiddle.net/G3SxU/

After user choose the date but decide to input the date using jquery ui datepicker, the radio checked should be cleared. Is there way to do this with Jquery or JS?.

I would liked the radio checked cleared when user click input field(From..)

```
`<li >
    <input id="time1" type="radio" name="radiohide" >
    <label for="time1" >Today</label>               
</li>
<li >
    <input id="time2" type="radio" name="radiohide" >
    <label for="time2" >Yesterday</label>       
</li>
<li  >
    <input id="time3" type="radio" name="radiohide" >
         <label for="time3" >3 Days ago</label>     
 </li>
 <li  >
    <input id="time4" type="radio" name="radiohide" >
    <label for="time4" >4 Days ago</label>              
</li>
<li>
         <input type="text" id="datepicker"  placeholder="From..."/>
</li>                 
<li>
         <input type="text" id="datepicker1" placeholder="To..." /> 
</li> 


  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });

      $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });`
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the radios in the onSelect function of the datePicker :

```
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      onSelect: function() {
          $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/G3SxU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/G3SxU/4/

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    }).on('change', function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    }).on('change', function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
  });
```

To reset the datepickers when a radio button is clicked, you can run:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#datepicker, #datepicker1').val('');
});
```

This is now in the JSFIDDLE linked above.

You can use the `onSelect` option of the [jQuery Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) as it will do the same thing as the more generic `change` event.

Comment: Thanks guys...one more question. How to reverse it, when after dates are picked but user checks the radio date and should clear the input field?

Comment: Updated my answer with how to do this.